# Справочник/сборник методов и функций

Tags: c++

Есть ли в С++ что-то подобное API из java, где описаны все методы?

API jav'ы в пример: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/ еще можно стандарт почитать

Comment: Еще можно (мне он больше нравится) http://www.cplusplus.com/